# Display array.length in highcharts

Tags: javascript, arrays, highcharts, data-visualization

I would like to display the arrayNam.Lenth/5 of several arrays in Highcharts. This doesn't work. What should I do differently?

```
$(function () {

     $('#number_container').highcharts({
         chart: {
             type: 'bar'
         },
         title: {
             text: 'Visualization'
         },
         xAxis: {
             categories: ['All', 'Basic', 'Intermediate', 'Advanced']
         },
         yAxis: {
             title: {
                 text: 'Number'
             }
         },
         series: [{
             name: 'Scans',
             data: [allScans.length / 5, 1, 4, 4]
         }]
     });
 }); < /script>
```

Comment: Why do you think it is not working? I used your code and it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/nwe8h0xp/ . Have you initialised `allScans` array? Is there any error in your browsers console?

Comment: This is from the console log:

allScansDataObjects
Array[985]
allScansDataObjects.length
985
allScansDataObjects.length/5
197

I shortened the name to allScans in the question name. The array seems to be working. And I don't get an error in the console. But the value 197 doesn't show up in the chart. There is just blank space in the All section.

Comment: Are the items added to the array before you initialise highcharts? It seems like the array is set to `[]` so length is 0 (you visualise value 0 - blank bar) and you probably push elements after the highcharts is initialised.

Comment: I guess data is loaded by AJAX - make sure you are creating chart inside the success callback.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs, folks. Yes Pawel, the data is loaded by AJAX. The problem is, I make several queries and the graph displays the length of arrays generated from all these queries. I carry out the AJAX queries in separate JS files for modularity and because I use the query results for multiple purposes. Is there another way to solve the problem?